# Question on Java generics type T vs WildCard

Tags: java, generics

I am a bit confused on how generic works, specially on when we should be using type `T` vs wildcard `?`.

I have the following:

```java
public interface EntityInfo {}

public class Individual implements EntityInfo {}

public abstract class Base<T extends EntityInfo> {}

public class Imp extends Base<Individual>{}

public abstract class BaseMapper<T extends Base<? extends EntityInfo>>{}

public class ImpMapper extends BaseMapper<Imp>{}
```

This compiles fine. But if I change `BaseMapper`: from `? extends EntityInfo` to `S extends EntityInfo`, the compiler will complain:

1. On BaseMapper: `Unexpected bound`
2. On ImpMapper: `Type parameter 'Imp' is not within its bound; should extend 'Base<S>'`

I am unsure how this works, why does wildcard work here and specific type will cause the compilation error?

Could anyone help me understand/explain the above?

Comment: This is tantamount to asking 'can someone write me a tutorial about generics' which is.. perhaps something along the lines of at least 100 pages. Well beyond what Stack Overflow is meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between using a wildcard and a specific type parameter is how Java handles generics during compilation.

When you use the wildcard `?`, it represents an unknown type that extends the given bound. It allows any subtype of the given bound to be used, but the specific type information is lost. This is useful when you want to allow a wide range of types without specifying the exact type.

However, when you use a specific type parameter, such as `S extends EntityInfo`, it signifies that you want to have a concrete type that extends `EntityInfo`. This allows you to use that type information within the class definition.

In the context of the code you provided:

- The code compiles fine when you use `? extends EntityInfo` in the
  `BaseMapper` class:

  ```
  public abstract class BaseMapper<T extends Base<? extends EntityInfo>>{}
  ```

  This works because the type parameter `T extends Base` with an unknown
  subtype of `EntityInfo`. So, when you create the `ImpMapper` class:

  ```
  public class ImpMapper extends BaseMapper<Imp>{}
  ```

  `Imp` is a valid type, as it extends `Base<Individual>`, and `Individual` implements `EntityInfo`.
- The code does not compile when you replace the wildcard with a specific type parameter:

  ```
  public abstract class BaseMapper<T extends Base<S extends EntityInfo>>{}
  ```

  This is because you are trying to declare a type parameter `S` within the bounds of another type parameter `T`. This is not valid syntax in Java. Instead, you should declare the type parameter separately:

  ```
  public abstract class BaseMapper<S extends EntityInfo, T extends Base<S>>{}
  ```

  Now, when you try to create the `ImpMapper` class:

  ```
  public class ImpMapper extends BaseMapper<Imp>{}
  ```

  You will still encounter a compilation error because `BaseMapper` expects two type parameters, but you only provided one (`Imp`). To fix this, provide both type parameters:

  ```
  public class ImpMapper extends BaseMapper<Individual, Imp>{}
  ```

  This will compile successfully since `Imp extends Base<Individual>`, and `Individual` implements `EntityInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, you should try and always used declared type `T` as it provides more secure types, and only use `?` as the last resort (or, when you exactly know what you're doing).

To answer the second part of your question, let me use your example:

```java
public abstract class Base<T extends EntityInfo> {}

public abstract class BaseMapper<T extends Base<? extends EntityInfo>>{}
```

When declaring a class with generics, you can only declare generic types right between `<>` brackets of *that* class. So for `Base`, you can declare `T` right in `Base<>`. But for your second example, you can correctly declare `T` in `BaseMapper<T>`, but the second generic type (the one you tried to declare `S`) is no longer in the brackets of `BaseMapper`, it's in bracket of another class (a class, that's not being declared right now). In Java, there's a difference between declaring a class and using the class as a type. In your example, `Base<? extends EntityInfo>` is a class that's being *used* in declaration (similarly to how class `Integer` has to already exist when declaring `List<Integer>`). You might very well declare `BaseMapper` and use `Base<>` as its generic type, but that used `BaseMapper` will need to have the generic type specified. You tried to specify type `S`, but that type wasn't declared anywhere in the declaraton of `BaseMapper`.

For it to work, you would need:

- Declare type `S` that extends `EntityInfo`
- Declare type `S` that extends `EntityInfo<S>`

Something similar to this:

```java
public abstract class Base<T extends EntityInfo> {}

public abstract class BaseMapper<S extends EntityInfo, T extends Base<S>>{}
```

Your problem really reflects the lack of knowledge on how Java generics work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. You are correct and I should take more time in learning java generics and how it actually works.